# How to import data into numbers properly

Tags: numbers

So I have a file with data, see link below:

http://www.epsilon-uitgaven.nl/bijlagen/E76/E76-tweelingdata.txt

I'm trying to import this into numbers, but what I get is the following:
[image]

Instead of having separate columns for 1, 167, 2, and 4 (this is the first cell), I just have one column for the entire data. I would like to separate this and have 5 separate columns, but I have no idea how.

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The datum need to be separated by commas, like so:

fam, lengte, gender, twin

1, 167, 2, 4

1, 167, 2, 4

[image]